# How can I determine a CNN model to train a multiple labels for image classifications?

Tags: python, image, pytorch, conv-neural-network, classification

I need your kind help.
How can I determine a CNNs model to train a multiple labels for image classification?

My data is a bunch of spectra. Each spectrum has 4 labels. How can I build a CNN to classify those images.

- How to compose the forward function and initialization function
- What kinds of layers do you recommend?

First, the metadata structure goes like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTK3m.png)

Here is my Dataset

```
class OurDataset(Dataset):
spectra_dir = f"./data/spectrograms_fm"
metaData_path = f"./data/FMAudio/metaData.csv"

def __init__(self):
    self.audio_labels = panda.read_csv(self.metaData_path)
    self.transform = torchvision.transforms.Compose([
        torchvision.transforms.Resize((201, 81)),
        torchvision.transforms.ToTensor()
    ])

def __len__(self):
    return len(self.audio_labels)

def __getitem__(self, idx):
    img = PILImage.open(f"./data/spectrograms_fm/mutiplelabels/{self.audio_labels.iloc[idx, 8]}.png").convert("RGB")
    img = self.transform(img)
    label_A = torch.tensor(self.audio_labels.iloc[idx, 4])
    label_Fw = torch.tensor(self.audio_labels.iloc[idx, 5])
    label_P = torch.tensor(self.audio_labels.iloc[idx, 6])
    label_Fi = torch.tensor(self.audio_labels.iloc[idx, 7])
    return img, label_A, label_Fw, label_P, label_Fi
```

I defined the training function

```
    def train(dataloader, model, loss, optimizer):
    model.train()
    size = len(dataloader.dataset)
    for batch, (img_tensors, Y_A, Y_Fw, Y_P, Y_Fi) in enumerate(dataloader):
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        pred = model(img_tensors.float())
        loss_A = cost(pred, Y_A)
        loss_Fw = cost(pred, Y_Fw)
        loss_P = cost(pred, Y_P)
        loss_Fi = cost(pred, Y_Fi)
        loss = loss_A + loss_Fw + loss_P + loss_Fi
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
```

I used the official CNN model from Microsoft pytorch tutorial image classification which is not apt to my case.

```
class CNNet(nn.Module):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 32, kernel_size=5)
    self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=5)
    self.conv2_drop = nn.Dropout2d()
    self.flatten = nn.Flatten()
    self.fc1 = nn.Linear(2112, 50)
    self.fc2 = nn.Linear(50, 4)


def forward(self, x):
    x = F.relu(F.max_pool2d(self.conv1(x), 4))
    x = F.relu(F.max_pool2d(self.conv2_drop(self.conv2(x)), 4))
    x = self.flatten(x)
    x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
    x = F.dropout(x, training=self.training)
    x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
    return F.log_softmax(x,dim=1)
```

Can you write my a demo?

Cheers

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This question is too broad and doesn't fit the criteria here on Stack Overflow. You need to ask about specific issues with defined constraints, with a minimal and reproducible example.